# Kivy: Kivy syntax to Python syntax

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using Kivy to build a small app and one thing I have to do is empty a Stacklayout which is in a ScrollView. I empty the Stackview in my .kv file with the syntax:
`for i in range(len(sgl.children)): sgl.remove_widget(sgl.children[0])` where "sgl" is the id of the Stacklayout.

Is there a python syntax that I can use in my .py file that would accomplish the same thing?

NOTE: I am referencing the id from another class. I'm unsure if that will be a problem.

Comment: Try using the `clear_widgets()` method.

Comment: Could I see the full syntax of that? Is it like ```classA.ids.sgl.clear_widgets()```?

Comment: The `clear_widgets()` method is a method of any widget. Without seeing your code, I cannot provide exact syntax. But `a.clear_widgets()` will remove all children of the widget instance `a`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.clear_widgets).